# getting started with mypy / ignoring external libs

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to run `mypy` type hints and just get a lot of errors for external libraries.

I've checked [this topic in the docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-type-hints-for-third-party-library)

and have a `mypy.ini` like this:

```
# Global options:

[mypy]
python_version = 3.8
; warn_return_any = True
; warn_unused_configs = True

# Per-module options:

[httplib2]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[google.cloud]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

but when I run mypy it still fills the console with these errors.
And, ironically, doesn't find any deliberate errors in my own code.

```
(venv) dcollier@dcsan:~/dev/kzen$ mypy cxutils/digger/chat_stat.py 
cxutils/gbot.py:11: error: Skipping analyzing 'httplib2': found module but no type hints or library stubs
cxutils/logit.py:10: error: Skipping analyzing 'google.cloud': found module but no type hints or library stubs
cxutils/logit.py:12: error: Skipping analyzing 'ansimarkup': found module but no type hints or library stubs
cxutils/biglib.py:18: error: Skipping analyzing 'pandas_gbq': found module but no type hints or library stubs

... etc
```

I'm using mypy in a virtualenv and `which mypy` confirms this.

Comment: The syntax is `[mypy-httplib2]`.  Alternatively, you can edit your code so it reads `import httplib2 # type ignore`.

Comment: thanks! so every import should be prefixed with `[mypy-...` ?

Comment: Yes.  And by the way, I learned this by reading the documentation, which you could have done as well.  https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html

Comment: i linked to the docs above but misread from the examples. thanks so much for pointing that out, I will rtfm again next time!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by prepending each module with `mypy-`, like this:

```ini
...

[mypy-httplib2]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-google.cloud]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

Or you can use the `pyproject.toml` file with the following content instead of the `mypy.ini` file:

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = [
    "httplib2",
    "google.cloud",
]
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

BTW, `pyproject.toml` allows you to configure additional tools besides the `mypy` (e.g. `isort`).
Also, note the syntax differences of `.toml` & `.ini` files.